# $X=\mathcal{N}(0,7)$ Calculate $E(e^{λX})$ for any $λ ∈ C$ and $E(X^7 − 3X^2 + 12X − 4)$.

Tags: probability

For the first part, I get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\lambda x}\cdot e^{\frac{-x^2}{14}}}{\sqrt{14\pi}}dx$$

In the integral, the way forward is to complete the square internally right? And hopefully end up with $\int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}$ form? I get the answer as $$e^{\frac{7\lambda^2}{2}}$$

Is this expression correct?

For the second part, can someone provide a hint as to how to go about it? Do I need to simply integrate each term?

Comment: The answer is correct. You can read off the expectations from the moment generating function you just calculated. But the second problem is in fact very easy, For $E(X^7)=0$ by symmetry.  And since the mean of $X$ is $0$, $E(X^2)$ is equal to the variance of $X$. Now use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Yes. You're right. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you have computed $\mathsf{E}(e^{\lambda X})$, this is moment generating function. And from MGF you can get any moment as follows
\begin{equation}
e^{\lambda X}=1+\lambda X+ \frac{\lambda^2X^2}{2!}+\frac{\lambda^3X^3}{3!}+...
\end{equation}
hence taking expectation from both sides
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{E}(e^{\lambda X})=1+\lambda\mathsf{E}(X)+\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}\mathsf{E}(X^2)+...
\end{equation}
Now in similar way expand the MGF which you have computed in first part. Now whatever moment you need compare the respective power, e.g., you need $\mathsf{E}(X^7)$ compare $7^{th}$ power on both sides and so on.

Comment: So I expand $e^\frac{7\lambda^2}{2} = 1 +\frac{7\lambda^2}{2} \frac{({\frac{7\lambda^2}{2})}^2}{2!}+\ldots$ on 1 side and the expression you gave on the other side. It looks like only even powers of $\lambda$ exist. So $E(X^7)$ and $E(X)$ don't exist (well mean is 0 is given).

Comment: Actually it is well known result that odd moments of zero mean Gaussian random variable are all zero. We can't say they do not exist rather, they are all zero.